# De Morgan’s Laws and with inverse images

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I want to prove $$f^{-1}(\bigcup_{\alpha \in A} E_{\alpha}) = \bigcup_{\alpha \in A}f^{-1}(E_{\alpha})$$

I have done a similar proof with Demorgans laws

$$\big(\bigcup_{\alpha \in A}E_{\alpha}\big)^c = \bigcap_{\alpha \in A}^c$$ This is of course assuming That $X$ be a set and ${E_{\alpha}}_{\alpha \in A}$ be a collection of subsets of $X$. $E^c$ represents the set $X/E$

This a direct proof let:

$$x \in \big(\bigcup_{\alpha \in A}E_{\alpha}\big)^c$$

then $$ x \notin \bigcup_{\alpha \in A}E_{\alpha} \space \forall \alpha \in A$$

Thus $$x \in E_{\alpha}^c \space \space \forall \space \alpha \in A$$

$$x \in \bigcap_{\alpha \in A} E_{\alpha}^c$$

Don't try to correct my above proof I already presented it in class. The following does not need to be a formal proof. Just a set of logical steps like in this one. This is an introductory class in Real analysis.

So now my question that I am looking for verification in:

If ${E_{\alpha}}_{\alpha \in A}$ is a collection of subsets in $Y$ then:

$$f^{-1}(\bigcup_{\alpha \in A} E_{\alpha}) = \bigcup_{\alpha \in A}f^{-1}(E_{\alpha})$$

$x \in f^{-1}(\bigcup_{\alpha \in A} E_{\alpha})$ iif $x = f(y)$ for some $y \in E_{\alpha}$

which is equivalent to saying that $x \in \bigcup f^{-1}(E_{\alpha})$ proving this backwards is entirely redundant because it is the same steps in reverse.

Comment: Your second equation has $\bigcap\limits_{\alpha\in A}^c$, where I presume you meant $\bigcap\limits_{\alpha\in A}E_\alpha^c$.

Comment: Also set minus should be written $X\setminus E$ `X\setminus E` or $X\smallsetminus E$ `X\smallsetminus E`.

Comment: With those corrections does the logic in the second one follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first proof needs a little polishing, but is on the right trail.   In short, for an arbitrary $x$: $$\begin{align}x\in (\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}E_\alpha)^\complement&\iff x\in X\land(x\notin\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}E_\alpha)\\&\iff x\in X\land \neg(\exists \alpha\in A~.x\in E_\alpha)\\[1ex]&\iff x\in X\land\forall\alpha\in A~.x\notin E_\alpha\\[1ex]&\iff \forall \alpha\in A~.x\in E_\alpha^\complement\\[1ex]&\iff x\in \bigcap_{\alpha\in A} E_\alpha^\complement\end{align}$$

---

Likewise your second proof checks out okay.

$$\begin{align}x\in f^{-1}(\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}E_\alpha)&\iff \exists y\in \bigcup_{\alpha\in A}E_\alpha~.y=f(x) 
\\[1ex]&\iff \exists y~.\exists \alpha\in A~.(y\in E_\alpha\wedge y=f(x))
\\[1ex]&\iff \exists \alpha\in A~.\exists y\in E_\alpha~.y=f(x)
\\[1ex]&\iff \exists \alpha\in A~.x\in f^{-1}(E_\alpha)
\\[1ex]&\iff x\in \bigcup_{\alpha\in A} f^{-1}(E_\alpha) 
\end{align}$$